# mat autocomplete get selected id value

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using the reactive form which contains un autocomplete input for list of users, when i select the user , in the formcontrol i obtain the whole object of the user, and if i change the value of option form [value]=user to [value]=user.id , it showing the id instead of the full name of user , i need to get just the id of the user object

this is my form group

```
this.invoiceForm = new FormGroup({
      user: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, autocompleteAdminValidator()]),
      creditType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      value: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      amount: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });


displayFn(user: USer) {
    return user ? user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName : undefined;
 }
```

HTML file

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>User</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="user" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{ option.firstName + ' ' + option.lastName }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-error *ngIf="invoiceForm.controls['user'].hasError('invalidUSer')"> user invalide </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

if i use (optionSelected)="selected($event) i obtains undefined undefined in the input

```
 selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
 this.invoiceForm.get('user').setValue((event.option.value as User).id);
}
```

the submited object is like this :

```
user: {id: 7, firstName: 'john', lastName: 'smith', phone: '124678', country: null, …}
amount: 1200
creditType: "PPF"
value: 120
```

i need to send just the id of user